# Powershell Active Directory commands not working in Powershell session

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

When I run an Active Directory related PowerShell command in a PowerShell session, I get this error:

> Get-ADUser : Unable to find a default server with Active Directory Web Services running.

This is the code which I used:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "test@b1234" -AsPlainText -Force

$cred= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("stackuser", $password )

$sess = New-PSSession -Credential $cred -ComputerName 'windows'

Enter-PSSession $sess

Get-ADUser -Identity 'krbtgt'

Exit-PSSession

Remove-PSSession $sess
```

The answer I am expecting is to get the details from AD

Comment: That error infers that ADWS (Active Directory Web Services) isn't running on a contactable Domain Controller. I believe it's enabled by default install now but in older OS versions it wasn't and has to be enabled as a feature.

Comment: Also, the `*-PSSession` cmdlets are intended for interactive use. For non-interactive execution use `Invoke-Command`.

Comment: Thank you so much i did both suggestion  i am getting the desired output
Below is my new code:
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "test@b1234" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("stackuser", $password )
$sess = New-PSSession -Credential $cred -ComputerName 'windows'
Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock {Import-Module Activedirectory }
Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock {Get-ADUser -Identity 'krbtgt' }
Exit-PSSession
Remove-PSSession $sess.Id

Comment: Don't post code as a comment. Either incorporate it into your question or, as it is an answer, answer your own question with it.