# Do we need Active Directory Domain Controller to run any PowerShell commands?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory, windows-10

I am trying to run a Powershell script which calls `Get-ADUser` command.
Something similar to this question [Powershell Active Directory commands not working in Powershell session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57671154/powershell-active-directory-commands-not-working-in-powershell-session)
But I am getting error `Get-ADUser : Unable to find a default server with Active Directory Web Services running.`

I have Imported the ActiveDirecotry Module and also run the Connect-AzureAD command.

Is it must to have the AD domain controller for running the Powershell commands?
Can we run Powershell commands like `Get-ADUser` just using the credentials of the Active Directory Admin?

Comment: The cmdlets in the AD Module are meant to manage AD / AD LDS so, yes you need a Domain Controller...

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Can I setup my Windows 10 Pro Laptop as a Active Directory Domain Controller for running the Powershell script?

Comment: No you can't, you need Windows Server.

Comment: You can setup a VM using Hyper-V with winServer 2019+ installed.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way I can bulk update the AD users other than the powershell script or the apps that we get in the market?

Comment: You need to be able to _connect_ to a domain controller to use the cmdlets. Either on a classic DC or a managed one in the cloud. Thus, to climb out of the [XY](https://xyproblem.info/) problem pit, [edit] the question and explain the bigger picture of what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I think the other way is to use the Powershell Microsoft Graph SDK OR Microsoft Graph Intune SDK, which does not require the DC and can work using the token or user authentication.

Comment: I think you have a confusion between what AD and Azure AD are

Comment: *"I have Imported the ActiveDirecotry Module and also run the Connect-AzureAD command."* - The ActiveDirectory module is for on-premesis AD (hosted yourself in Windows Server). `Connect-AzureAD` is for AzureAD (AD hosted by Microsoft). They are for different things. Even in a hybrid environment (on-prem AD synced with AzureAD), you would rarely use both the ActiveDirectory module and `Connect-AzureAD` in the same script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The `ActiveDirectory` module cmdlets installed with `RSAT Tools` need to communicate with Active Directory infrastructure to retrieve information about the domain and objects stored within it.

This generally (if not wholly) encompasses other first-party PowerShell modules integrating with Active Directory services outside of ADDS as well; the services need to be communicable for the PowerShell modules to function correctly.

---

However, you have a fundamental misunderstanding of the differences between Active Directory and Azure AD. They are separate services and do not function the same way. At a high level:

- **Active Directory** is the self-hosted on-prem directory services solution provided by Microsoft. This is the fully-functional AD you have known and loved since 1999.

  Generally administered with the `RSAT Tools` feature and the `ActiveDirectory` PowerShell module it installs.
- **Azure AD** is a completely separate managed-directory service available from Microsoft in Azure. It does not provide anywhere close to a 1:1 feature parity with on-prem **Active Directory**. That isn't to say it is a *lesser* product; it is simply a *different* product.

  It is worth a mention that there are handy features available with **Azure AD** that you don't get with on-prem **Active Directory**. Generally administered via the Azure Portal, or the `Az.*` PowerShell modules available from the PowerShell Gallery.

You cannot use the `ActiveDirectory` module to manage **Azure AD** just as you cannot use the `Az.*` modules to manage on-prem **Active Directory**. You can have both modules installed on a single system of course, you just need to use the correct module with the correct service.